# Trying to place the canvas interactive cubes onDocumentMouseDown() function on a rotating cube. I'm having problems. why?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I borrowed this open source cube from one of the tutorial websites:

```
<script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/Three.js">
</script>
<script>
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback){
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback){
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

function animate(lastTime, angularSpeed, three){
    // update
    var date = new Date();
    var time = date.getTime();
    var timeDiff = time - lastTime;
    var angleChange = angularSpeed * timeDiff * 2 * Math.PI / 1000;
    three.cube.rotation.y += angleChange;
    lastTime = time;

    // render
    three.renderer.render(three.scene, three.camera);

    // request new frame
    requestAnimFrame(function(){
        animate(lastTime, angularSpeed, three);
    });
}

window.onload = function(){
    var angularSpeed = 0.2; // revolutions per second
    var lastTime = 0;

    // renderer
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // camera
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 700;

    // scene
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // material
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0x0000ff
    });

    // cube
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(300, 300, 300), material);
    cube.overdraw = true;
    scene.add(cube);

    // add subtle ambient lighting
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555555);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    // add directional light source
    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    // create wrapper object that contains three.js objects
    var three = {
        renderer: renderer,
        camera: camera,
        scene: scene,
        cube: cube
    };

    animate(lastTime, angularSpeed, three);
};
```

And it generates a blue rotating cube.

I want to add these interactive elements of the canvas interactive cubes. Specifically the function that allows upon a user click to add dots to the cube or object detected from the rays.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html

Using the function below in the cube code doesn't work. Why? Can anyone explain the basics to me and what I'm suppose to change for this cube or let's say any other object? Where am I supposed to place this code in my code?

This is my code below with the mixed elements. Why is it not working?

```
<script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/Three.js">
</script>
<script>
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback){
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback){
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

function animate(lastTime, angularSpeed, three){
    // update
    var date = new Date();
    var time = date.getTime();
    var timeDiff = time - lastTime;
    var angleChange = angularSpeed * timeDiff * 2 * Math.PI / 1000;
    three.cube.rotation.y += angleChange;
    lastTime = time;

    // render
    three.renderer.render(three.scene, three.camera);

    // request new frame
    requestAnimFrame(function(){
        animate(lastTime, angularSpeed, three);
    });
}

window.onload = function(){
    var angularSpeed = 0.2; // revolutions per second
    var lastTime = 0;

    // renderer
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // camera
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 700;

    // scene
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // material
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0x0000ff
    });

    // cube
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(300, 300, 300), material);
    cube.overdraw = true;
    scene.add(cube);

    // add subtle ambient lighting
    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555555);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    // add directional light source
    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    // create wrapper object that contains three.js objects
    var three = {
        renderer: renderer,
        camera: camera,
        scene: scene,
        cube: cube
    };

    animate(lastTime, angularSpeed, three);


function init() { 

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
            particleMaterial = new THREE.ParticleCanvasMaterial( {

                color: 0x000000,
                program: function ( context ) {

                    context.beginPath();
                    context.arc( 0, 0, 1, 0, PI2, true );
                    context.closePath();
                    context.fill();

                }

            } );

            projector = new THREE.Projector();

            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
            container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }


function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

            event.preventDefault();

            var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
            projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

            var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

            if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

                intersects[ 0 ].object.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );

                var particle = new THREE.Particle( particleMaterial );
                particle.position = intersects[ 0 ].point;
                particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 8;
                scene.add( particle );

            }

             }; 

             };
```

Essentially I'm trying to learn three.js and how to apply different features but I'm still a newbie to Javascript let alone webGL or three.js, so perhaps I'm missing a fundamental.

Thank you!!

Comment: Start over. Do not copy examples from the net. They are old and outdated. Only refer to official three.js examples which are consistent with the current version, r.56. You are linking to r.45, which is a year old. Also, saying "it doesn't work" is not informative. Ask a specific question.

Comment: My question is why the function onDocumentMouseDown() isn't generating a particle when the user clicks the object?

Comment: Did you follow my adivce and link to the current version r.56? Do you have console errors?

Comment: For a collection of examples that work with v56, check out: http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/

Comment: @LeeStemkoski, Thanks. I figured that out. But this is my latest problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455597/how-can-i-make-the-label-im-using-appear-only-once-upon-a-click-and-disappear-w. I figured out how to do it with color but I'm not entirely use how to have text clickable once and then restore an object without the text. Should I be using the texture attribute instead of color?